# What happened to the links to a Stack App mentioned in the documentation about write access?

Tags: support, bug, api-v2.2, documentation, write-access

The [documentation about write access](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/write) states:

> The application responsible for creating content via the API may be indicated with a link to an app's Stack Apps post. The exact manner of display is subject to change at any time.
>
> For example, API created comments current look like the following when hovered over:
>
> [image]

Is this still accurate? I can't remember seeing this at all – maybe because it would affect comments from the mobile app too, causing too much noise? Or does "subject to change at any time" mean "we've disabled this for now and it's highly unlikely to come back"?

Anyway, it's probably better to remove it.

Comment: This comment added via API.

Answer (score 3):

This is a documentation bug in my opinion.  The "via Example App" was never included, nor should it be.

1. A **user is fully responsible for his or her content**, it doesn't, and shouldn't, matter *how* that content was posted. Whether via: the web page, the Android App, a custom Stack App, or via Pony Express -- the content is what matters.
2. A rogue app would quickly be dropped and/or reported by its users, or others, regardless.
3. Such a message would be just as useful and welcome as all those "Sent from my iPhone" emails and texts. That is, not at all.
4. Including that link is another vector of coding and UI headaches, for trivial or no gain.